# Unable to center input elements inside a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center elements inside a div. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4hpuj5no/):

I made a wrapper for the number inputs and trying to apply text-center property on them but it's not working. I also changed the display to block, but that doesn't solve it either. What am I missing?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning Ajax</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js">  </script>

    <!-- Or source it to http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js
         This will be faster as jquery website will be faster than mine. -->


    <style type="text/css">

        h1,h2
        {
            text-align:center;
        }

        .num1,.num2
        {
            text-align:center;
        }

        .inputs
        {
            text-align:center;
            display:block;
        }


    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <h1>Calculator</h1>

        <h2>Enter two numbers and select an operation</h2>

        <div id="inputs">

            <input id="num1">Number 1</input>

            <input id="num2">Number 2</input>

        </div>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: when writing css you identify ids with # and not .(dot)

Comment: eh, you are right. Just noticed that. Thanks for your help, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

try giving your #inputs a width and set left/right margins to auto.

```html
#inputs {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```